# No Method Masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to get masonry working with jQuery using the latest instructions at: http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

I have included the js file before the call. The call looks like this:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#main').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.post-outer',
          isAnimated: true,
          isFitWidth: true
        });
    });
  </script>
```

It does not work and outputs this error in my Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry'

Any idea why this happening?

EDIT: I have tried putting the call in the HEAD as well as the bottom of the BODY.

EDIT2: I tried the normal javascript call instead of the jQuery one. The error in my console now states that Masonry is not defined. As far as I can tell it is though...

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle of the problem? Not sure how to debug without the example.

Comment: I am unable to recreate the issue in jsFiddle, but you can see me trying to get it to work live here: http://www.xarpixels.com/search/label/Blog

Comment: Before your edit, I was going to say -- it's not loading masonry correctly. Where did you load the script? Is it hosted locally? From a CDN?

Comment: on a different domain, but it is has the correct path to the file. I tried putting it in the HEAD, the BODY, before & after the call, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not be loading masonry, or wherever you are trying to load it from is refusing the connection. The reason I say that is because this was my console session on your site.

```
> var masonry = new Masonry ( '#main' )
ReferenceError: Masonry is not defined // this tells me its not loaded
> var script = document.createElement("script"); // let's inject it
undefined
> script.type = "text/javascript";
"text/javascript"
> script.src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.1/masonry.pkgd.js"
"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.1/masonry.pkgd.js"
> document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( script )
<script type=​"text/​javascript" src=​"/​/​cdnjs.cloudflare.com/​ajax/​libs/​masonry/​3.1.1/​masonry.pkgd.js">​</script>​
> masonry
ReferenceError: masonry is not defined
> var masonry = new Masonry()
Bad masonry element: undefined masonry.pkgd.js:1621 // woohoo, we can tell it's loaded now
undefined
> var container = document.querySelector('#main');
undefined
> container
<div class=​"main section" id=​"main">​…​</div>​
> var masonry = new Masonry( container )
undefined
> masonry
// and we have it!
Layout {element: div#main.main section, options: Object, items: Array[1], stamps: Array[0], isResizeBound: true…}
```

Comment: It's working now since I went ahead and embedded it. I then noticed errors with other scripts that were breaking the masonry script. I wouldn't say this answer is the "correct" answer, but it helped me none-the-less. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery script tag should be loaded before masonry.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. You mean the script should be loaded before the masonry js file?

Answer (score 0):

same problem came with me then i will use my code like this way and  it works for me

so you may try this solution hope it will work

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
       jQuery.noConflict();
  (function($) {
            $('#main').masonry({
              itemSelector: '.post-outer',
              isAnimated: true,
              isFitWidth: true
            });
    })(jQuery);
      </script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry' Blog:6131
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function Blog:5709
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: Obviously this won't work... You said you tried it in pure javascript, with the same effect. Therefore, `noConflict()` makes no sense, as it's a jQuery function.

Comment: @brbcoding the script call is in jquery. Masonry 3.1.1 is supposed to work with or without jQuery.

Comment: Exactly, but you had the same issue when you used the vanilla js version. That's why I'm saying it's not a conflict problem with jQuery.